# Probability of Next Occurence

Tags: probability

I have collected data on the time duration between consecutive occurrences of a particular event ("success"), and the amount of time between consecutive "successes" (in days) seems to be distributed using a Gamma distribution.  Intuitively, this is not a Bernoulli trial because the probability of a "success" in a given day seems to increase the longer it has been since the previous "success".  I would like to know how to determine the probability that the next "success" will happen **today**.  That is, each day, it is known how long it has been since the last "success", but I would like to determine the probability that (given the knowledge of the last "success") the next "success" occurs **today**.

I would appreciate any insight into solving this problem.

**-- EDIT --**

I need to determine the probability that the next "success/arrival" occurs between n and n+1 days, i.e., the interval [n,n+1), after the last known "success", i.e., at day 0, **assuming that** no "successes" have occurred in the first n days, i.e., in the interval [0,n).

The collected data is the number of days between consecutive "successes", and this "arrival/waiting time" is Gamma distributed with parameters k and θ.  Is a non-homogeneous Poisson process the correct method?  If so, how can I determine the Poisson rate λ(t) from the Gamma distribution?  If I understand the Poisson process correctly, then I only want to know P{N[k,k+1)>0 | N[0,k)=0}.

Thoughts?

Comment: Have you considered modeling the arrival of “successes” as a Poisson process? The waiting time between arrivals is exponentially distributed and the time until the $j$-th arrival is gamma distributed. You can then calculate $P(N_t>0)$, the chance of at least one arrival in time $(0,t]$ and much more.

Comment: I have edited the original post.  Hopefully my update makes sense.

Comment: If the *waiting times* are gamma distributed then a *homogeneous* Poisson process with rate $\lambda$ is inappropriate because in such case the waiting times are independent and exponentially distributed with mean waiting time $1/\lambda$ and the *arrival times* are $\sim \Gamma(.,\lambda)$ that is the $n$-th success occurs after $T_n$ time where $T_n$ is gamma distributed with mean $n/\lambda$. I do not know off the top of my head if there is a choice for $\lambda(t)$ for non-homogeneous Poisson process that will result in IID Gamma waiting times but I’ll think look into it.

Comment: I make my second comment to reinforce the fact that you seem to overlook that the *arrival times of successes* and *waiting time between* successive successes are different RVs, in general. There is a relationship however: $T_n=W_1+\dotsc+W_n$. Further, by independent (time) increments of the Poisson process, the conditional probability you want reduces to the probability $P(N[0,1)>0)$.

Comment: My apologies. It appears, from your explanation, that I am wanting to find the probability that the next **waiting time** (not arrival time) is in [n, n+1) given that it is not in [0,n).

Comment: The wait times are not constant. They are gamma distributed, and so using a constant λ (unless I am misunderstanding, which is likely) seems incorrect.